APT dependency question
I am trying to install the dependencies to compile Strongswan, since the main packages appear to be broken.
When I attempt to install the libsoup package, I get the following error:
~/strongswan-5.9.14# apt install -f libsoup2.4-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libbrotli-dev : Depends: libbrotli1 (= 1.1.0-2build2) but 1.1.0-2+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed

This is on a server installation, recently upgraded to 24.04.1 LTS.
Update: package info
# apt policy libbrotli1
libbrotli1:
  Installed: 1.1.0-2+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 1.1.0-2+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.0-2+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.1.0-2build2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Packages


# apt-get remove libbrotli1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.191~) but it is not going to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.191~) but it is not installable or
                        base-files (< 12.3) but 13ubuntu10.1 is to be installed
               Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not going to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not installable
               Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

I see the package installed is from the ppa, and there is a package in the repos. What is the best / safe way to remove and re-install the repo package without breaking everything?

It looks like you have the Jammy release of ppa:ondrej/php in your sources

I did, server was recently upgraded from 22.04 and those were supposed to have been disabled on upgrade. I removed their sources.list files and it was still happening. I'll check and see if something else remains.

Edited with package info. How do I swap out the package from ppa to repo without breaking grub etc?

Thanks @steeldriver - your comment helped me to fix my own issue, couldn't install libmagickwand-dev because of the libbrotli1 issue described above. As I recently did an upgrade from Ubuntu 20 to 22, and was using the ppa:ondrej/php repo, I faced the same issue. I modified the apt sources to use the jammy distrib instead of focal, and it fixed the problem.

To solve this, I changed the pin priority of the repo:
in /etc/apt/preferences.d I created a file
lib.pref
Package: *
Pin: origin archive.ubuntu.com
Pin-Priority: 1001

After running
apt update,
apt policy libbrotli1 now showed:
apt policy libbrotli1
libbrotli1:
  Installed: 1.1.0-2+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 1.1.0-2build2
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.0-2+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.1.0-2build2 1001
       1001 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Packages

I was then able to re-install the package.
 apt reinstall libbrotli1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libbrotli1
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 331 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3072 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 libbrotli1 amd64 1.1.0-2build2 [331 kB]
Fetched 331 kB in 0s (679 kB/s)    
dpkg: warning: downgrading libbrotli1:amd64 from 1.1.0-2+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 to 1.1.0-2build2
(Reading database ... 119664 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libbrotli1_1.1.0-2build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libbrotli1:amd64 (1.1.0-2build2) over (1.1.0-2+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Setting up libbrotli1:amd64 (1.1.0-2build2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.39-0ubuntu8.3) ...
Scanning processes...                                                                                                                                    
Scanning candidates...                                                                                                                                   
Scanning linux images...                                                                                                                                 

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

Restarting services...
 systemctl restart clamav-freshclam.service packagekit.service php8.3-fpm.service sogo.service

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.

And then I could install the dependencies without issue.
I commented out the entries in lib.pref so as to not mess up future things, but it's there if there is another package that needs to be upgraded from the 22.04 ppa.

You could also use ppa-purge which removes all packages from the ppa, replaces them with repo packages if available, and deletes the ppa.

Great question and answer!
Check the output of sudo apt update to see full domain name of archive to go in lib.pref. In my case it was gb.archive.ubuntu.com not archive.ubuntu.com
